# Using XMLHttpRequest for File Upload On Localhost Does Not Trigger PHP Script

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get a simple upload system going using php and XMLHttpRequest. However I fail to achieve the goal using the request. It doesn't work..

Here is my HTML form which is used to get the image file:

```
<form action="../session/uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

and this is my PHP script which saves the image into my filesystem:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $target_dir = "../db/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
}
?>
```

Now this works perfectly fine but I want to use an XMLHttpRequest so that the page doesn't need to refresh when images are uploaded. I was trying to do something which seemed very straight forward but it didn't work..

first I changed the PHP to this:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "../db/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
?>
```

and right below my form in the HTML I've added some Javascript which makes the XMLHttpRequest and sends it:

```
<script>
    const uploadForm = document.getElementById("uploadForm");
    uploadForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "../session/uploader.php", true);  
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");    
        xhr.send(new FormData(uploadForm));                 
    });
</script>
```

The problem here is that it simply doesn't work. Nothing happens. I get no feedback. It's like the uploader.php script didn't get called.

Doesn anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

The submit button will not be included in the form submission data set here, as it would be if you had just send the form “normally”.

```
xhr.send(new FormData(uploadForm));
```

The browser has no idea here at this point, that you clicked the submit button to actually trigger the whole process - so it will only include the data for the `fileToUpload` file upload field, but not the submit button.

You can either add a hidden field, and then check if that is set within $_POST, or you check if `fileToUpload` is set directly (but remember, that one is going to be in $_FILES, not $_POST.)

---

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

A proper multipart request also needs to include the *boundary* that will be used to separate the parts inside the request body, in this header.

Using FormData, this should automatically get added, so remove this line - it is *overwriting* the correct header with one that is incomplete here at this point.

Comment: I sort of understand what you mean but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to change now.. can you add a little more code to show how the html, javascript and php files should actually look like. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Alright, removing `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");` inside the javascript did the trick. Thanks!!